# 502 Bad Gateway with Nginx Proxy On

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04, plesk, nginx-reverse-proxy

trying to setup a Discourse inside Plesk with Docker Image, and everything works when I use ip to connect to the installation, but when using the hostname on my testsystem, I get a 502 Bad Gateway after enabling Nginx to proxy. Here is the error log I get:

```
2018/04/01 20:44:48 [error] 10591#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.2.107, server: test.plesk.local, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:8060/favicon.ico", host: "test.plesk.local", referrer: "http://test.plesk.local/"
```

So as I said, I have no problems connecting with my test.plesk.local to any installation on my system, only when enabling the proxy, which I need as Discourse is running at 8060 for http and 9443 for https.Also after proxy setup I tried to connect via IP 192.168.2.114:8060 which leads me to the working Discourse installation.

Hope anyone has a solution for that. Thanks in advance.
Daniel